# How should I troubleshoot this isolated current loop?

Tags: analog, isolator

I'm using the [ADUM5211 Isolater](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum5211.html) and [ADA4528-2 Dual Op-Amp](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ada4528-2.html) to make an isolated current loop with range of 0 - 20 mA.  My circuit is below.  Unfortunately, when I apply 5V to the *5V0* net and 0V to the *nEN* pin, the *5V0ISO* net is 2.3V (I expected to get 5V).

Is there anything obviously wrong with this circuit?  What troubleshooting steps might help me diagnose this?

[image: Current Loop Circuit]

Answer (score 4):

You’ve apparently swapped the values of the two resistors that determine the isolated output voltage.

[image]